# In Geospatial Creator, not able to understand where to put the required object as Tile are generating in 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, geospatial, augmented-reality, arcore, google-map-tiles-api

I am currently working on the Geospatial Creator in Unity. I am facing some issues where in the Map which is generating after I give the latitude and longitude is in 2D, my location is Hyderabad, India. But, where in other locations are generating in 3D. I am planning to make an interactive AR App using this.

But, as you can see in the video and picture below, the Object does not get placed in the desired location I want even after giving it exactly where it should be.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqtSF.jpg)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToTfD.jpg)

Does anyone have a work around for this? And how to tackle this issue.

As you can see in the Pictures above, I have tried placing the object in different positions, but still the problem exists.